# Why is CMake find_package ignoring linker flags?

Tags: cmake, libtiff, cray

I'm developing on a Cray system that requires '-dynamic' be passed before dynamic libraries can be found. In my case I'm trying to link with libtiff. The command `cc main.cpp -ltiff` fails with a file not found but `cc main.cpp -dynamic -ltiff` works. I believe this file not found behavior is tripping up CMake's `find_package`.

When I use CMake (version 3.5.2) and pass `-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING="-dynamic"` from the command line `find_package(TIFF)` works. But when I set it in CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-dynamic")
find_package(TIFF REQUIRED)
```

it can't find libtiff. But if I try:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-dynamic" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
find_package(TIFF REQUIRED)
```

it fails the first time, but puts "-dynamic" in the cache and then works on the second run.
If I manually set `TIFF_LIBRARY_RELEASE` to point to the .so then `find_package` will also work (by filling out the rest of the variables).

What is the proper way of doing this without passing it as a parameter?

Comment: It is unlikely that `find_package` for TIFF uses `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable. E.g. the [one shipped with CMake itself](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindTIFF.cmake) doesn't use this variable. So your problem in finding TIFF has, probably, some other reasons than setting the variable `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.

Comment: While FindTIFF.cmake in /usr/share/cmake/Modules doesn't reference the variable it calls other functions that might. Clearly the parameter makes a difference because that's the only change I need to make to get it to work in a minimum example. My CMake file doesn't even build anything it's just those two lines plus the project declaration (to which I only provide a name).

Comment: "it fails the first time, but puts "-dynamic" in the cache and then works on the second run." - This smells like setting of `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` affects on the **compiler** detection, which is performed on `project()` call. This detection in turn may set additional directories for search a library or add additional library extensions. Since I am not very familiar with compilers on Cray, above are only a guess. You may try to set `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable **before** the `project()` call. This way your project would work identically both the first and following calls.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That's it. `find_package()` couldn't find it because the search paths came from the compiler and the search paths are different depending on the linker flags. When I moved  `set(...)`  before `project()` it didn't need the `CACHE` part either. Care to write up an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Tsyvarev's comment above:

Compilers are probed when you call project(). So in this case, where a compiler flag will change the library and include paths, you have to set CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS before calling project.

Answer (score 0):

For the Cray programming environment and dynamic linking, I usually find that it is best to set the environment variable `CRAYPE_LINK_TYPE=dynamic` before configuring and building. This usually plays nicer with any other modules that you may be using.

Comment: That is correct, but it’s not the point of the question. If I needed a different linker flag I’d still have the problem.